# Bootstrap the same Angular standalone component multiple times on one page

Tags: angular, typescript, micro-frontend, surveyjs

**Edit**

Thanks to the answer and comments by Andrew, I will change my approach:

- Switch from `survey-angular` to `survey-angular-ui` package
- Follow the approach per widget as detailed in [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/surveyjs-angular-forked-96o0np?file=/src/app/components/json.ts)
- Create a single module that declares all these components as well as registering them with the Serialiser:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ColorPickerModule } from 'ngx-color-picker';
import { ColorPickerComponent } from './color.component';
import { registerColorPicker } from './color.model';

// Register all components here
registerColorPicker();

@NgModule({
  // Declare all Angular components
  declarations: [ColorPickerComponent],
  // Import any library modules you need for your custom widgets
  imports: [ColorPickerModule],
})
export class CustomWidgetsModule {}
```

- Then import this `CustomWidgetsModule` in your main app module

I have left the old question title intact and body below for future reference.

---

I'm looking at the usage of standalone Angular components as a base for writing advanced widgets to be used as custom questions for [SurveyJS](https://surveyjs.io/).

My current approach is to generate an NgModule on the fly, configure it with the relevant imports and then bootstrap it to the HTML element of the custom question:

```js
afterRender: async (question: Question, el: HTMLDivElement) => {
  @NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule, ...],
    providers: [...],
  })
  class CustomQuestionModule implements DoBootstrap {
    ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef): void {
      appRef.bootstrap(widgetComponentClass, el);
    }
  }

  await platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(CustomQuestionModule);
}
```

With the introduction of [standalone components](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components#getting-started-with-standalone-components) in Angular 14 I thought I could get rid of the generated NgModule and use the [bootstrapApplication API](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/bootstrapApplication) to bootstrap the component.

This works for a single component. However if I have multiple identical standalone components, they all attach to the HTML element of the first one. In other words: I seem to be unable to bootstrap 2 identical standalone components to different HTML elements?

With the previous approach (as shown in the code example above), I could specify the element the module should bootstrap to. Is there an equivalent for this approach using standalone components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest stopping using afterRender.

We have introduced Angular rendering for SurveyJS survey-form runner and for Creator. You need to remove "survey-angular" package and use "survey-angular-ui" instead. "survey-angular" is a wrapper for survey for knockout JS. "survey-angular-ui" is an Angular rendering that uses platform independent "survey-core". You can find more [here](https://surveyjs.io/form-library/documentation/get-started-angular).

You can override our rendering using Angular component. Here is [the example](https://surveyjs.io/form-library/examples/dropdown-box-with-custom-items/angular#content-code) of changing choice item rendering in dropdown question.
We are working to make SurveyJS libraries  a Lego constructor, where almost any part can be overridden by a custom component, Angular or React based on platform.

Thank you,

Andrew, SurveyJS Team

Comment: Thank you for your answer Andrew. Does this also apply to fully custom created widgets (cfr: https://surveyjs.io/survey-creator/documentation/create-custom-widget)? In other words, can I use the `AngularComponentFactory` to register custom question types?

Comment: @thomaux Sure, Here is [the example](https://codesandbox.io/s/surveyjs-angular-forked-21gngf?file=/src/app/components/json.ts) of using ngx-color-picker. It uses "renderAs" functionality, but you can define it as a new question type. Futher, you can use this "renderAs" or a new question type as property editor in the Property Grid in Creator V2 for Angular. In fact, Property Grid in Creator V2 is our survey widget, as all other form entry widgets in Creator V2 in Logic tab, Translation tab and others. - Andrew

Comment: Thank you Andrew, that looks interesting. Is there a way to set the default rendering of a custom question type? I would like to avoid having to add the `renderAs` property in addition to the custom question type

Comment: Here is [the example](https://codesandbox.io/s/surveyjs-angular-forked-96o0np?file=/src/app/components/json.ts) of creating new question type "colorpicker" using ngx-color-picker component.

Comment: Thank you Andrew! This seems like a much cleaner solution than what I was trying to achieve